# Send Laravel 5.5 mail using gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have been getting an error while i try to send an email using laravel 5.5 with gmail.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmailadress
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I changed the mail host from smtp.google.com to that one becuase i could not reach smtp.google.com

Here is the error i get when i try to send mail

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`smtp.gmail.com' did not match expected CN=`gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com'
```

And this is the error that i use when i use mail_host smtp.google.com

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.google.com 
[php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0
```

Note that everything was working well with my testing server mailtrap. So how can i make this work for production?

Answer (score 5):

you have error in mail host   `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`

As per your question you have used `MAIL_HOST=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com` and `MAIL_HOST=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com`

But gmail host is `smtp.gmail.com`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmailadress
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Usually setting encryption to ssl works:

```
'encryption' => 'ssl'
```

On your `config/mail.php`:

But you better try to stick with `smtp.gmail.com`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmailadress
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: ssl is less secure then tls and it seems turned off for gmail, I could not connect using ssl but it worked just fine using tls